# syntax error near unexpected token `newline' in .bashrc

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

I'm trying to add script

```
function proxyset() {
        proxy_enabled=true

        NO_PROXY_DOMAINS=".abc.com,"
        LOCAL_ADDRESSES="localhost"

        USER=<USER_ID>
        PASSWORD=<URL_ENCODED_PASSWORD>
        SERVER=httppxgot.abc.com
        PORT=8080

# Disable HTTP proxy
function proxyunset() {
        unset NO_PROXY
        echo 'Im unset!'
}
```

but when I'm opening cygwin terminal its showing

```
syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
-bash: /cygdrive/c/Users/XXX/.bashrc: line 214: `        USER=<USER_ID>'
```

whats is wrong with script

Comment: bash function doesn't accept `-` in its name. Check that!

Comment: sure that works:

`function echo-test() { echo test ;}; echo-test`

Comment: There is a missing close bracket for the firs function.

Comment: Cygwin is not Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

As it says, bash can not handle the line 214 in which the USER variable is set to 
I don't know what you want to fill in there but the signs '<' and '>' are used in bash for redirecting output therefore the variable cannot be set.

Example:

```
bash-4.4$ USER=<USER_ID>
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

bash-4.4$ USER=test<
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

bash-4.4$ USER=test
bash-4.4$ echo $USER
test
```

If you want to get your actual username or id either use the command `id` or look with `export` for Environment Variables which already exists.

For more information about I/O redirection have a look at the docs: https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html